# apache ignite upgrade from 2.8.1 to 2.10.0

Tags: ignite

I upgraded apache ignite from 2.8.1 to 2.10.0 and now get **"class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to resolve .NET class 'IFS.Base.Models.RqrsModels.PublicMessageModels.InstTrade' in Java [platformId=0, typeId=1775204339]."** exception.
What's the problom?

Answer (score 0):

Ignite 2.10 has a bug related to incorrect metadata handling for indexed types: [IGNITE-14856](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-14856)

Please roll back to 2.9.1 or wait for 2.11 which is expected within a month.

Comment: I found out if I set SqlFieldQuery attribute on just one of the properties of the model it solves the problem, but I don't want to do it because it's work on 2.8.1 version truly and doesn't need to change.
I downgrade to 2.8.1 version, I hope this bug fix in the new version.